# Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel showing Blank Page

Tags: php, html, dynamic, bootstrap-4, carousel

I was making a Dynamic Bootstrap Carousel using PHP. I was watching this and making it: [Dynamic BootStrap Carousel](https://www.vivekmoyal.in/how-to-create-dynamic-image-slider-using-php-and-bootstrap/)

But I got stuck at a place where I am getting a blank page with no error, no source code on inspect element! My code is bit different than the actual link code which is given above.
Here is my code:

```html
<?php
require 'php/dbh.inc.php'; //Database Connection File

$select= 'SELECT*FROM projects;';
$result= mysqli_query($conn, $select);
$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($count<1){
echo "No rows found!";
}
else{
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $rows[]=$row;  //Mostly this section is the problem
  }
  return $rows;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script >
    $(function(){
                $("#includedContent").load("include.html");
            });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="includedContent"></div>

<div id="home">
    <div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="3"></li>
    <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" data-slide-to="4"></li> 
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="Images/Menu/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Images/Menu/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Images/Menu/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Images/Menu/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="Images/Menu/5.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-content">
            <h3>First Slide</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
  
<div id="about">
  <h1 class="about-head">About Me</h1>
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="textimg">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
 <img src="Images/sample.png" class="img-fluid"> 
</div>
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12">
  <p>
My name is Kabir Jhangiani, I am an aspiring photojournalist. I reside in this busy city Mumbai, where observing people, their events & capturing the most of it those daily lives became my favourite past time. I want to speak a story through a picture that not only shows what it shows but also speaks out my mind. It’s very interesting to observe people, their activities & what’s happening in their surroundings. My interest towards Street photography started getting more intense when I started covering events & cultures from Ganesh Festival to Muharram.
I would like to capture all of these moments on my camera to speak your style of story through my words. Painters express their art through paint, writers through words, I would like to capture the moments through emotions in them.
I am very fond of documenting different festivals, it talks about the history of the festival and the reasons behind it to celebrate.
Photography to me is, creating history, when we live in the future, we can live in the moment while looking at its visuals. 
  </p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="work">
  <h1 class="work-head">Work</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="workCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <?php
      $i=0;
      if(count($rows)){
        foreach ($rows as $value) {
          if($i==0){
            echo '<li data-target="#workCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>';
            $i++;
          }else{
            echo '<li data-target="#workCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>';
            $i++;
          }
        }
      }
      ?>
  </ol>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
      $a=0;
      if(count($rows)){
        foreach ($rows as $value) {
          if($a==0){
            echo '<div class="carousel-item active">
                    <img src="Images/Projects/'.$value["ImageName"].'" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>';
            $a++;
          }else{
            echo ' <div class="carousel-item">
                    <img src="Images/Projects/'.$value["ImageName"].'" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  </div>';
            $a++;
          }
        }
      }
      ?>
   
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
    </div>
  </div>
   <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#workCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#workCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Mostly according to me the problem is in the while loop section or require line because when i comment that section, my content shows up. Please help!

Comment: Your carousel is not dynamic. Its static. The reason I say this is due the fact that you are loading all the information as you create the page. I would advice to separate your code. You should have a page in which using JavaScript, you call an endpoint, written in php, that will return a JSON with the content to display.

Comment: What is JSON? Sorry I don't know

Comment: Sure, I can guide you. JSON is a format to transmit information such as XML. My advice to you is that you find some tutorial on how to use REST calls using JavaScript and PHP. By doing that, you will be able to understand any solution that is given to you.

Comment: Is there any other way without learning JSON to make a dynamic carousel?